# Node express mongoose directory structure best practices

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I found this library structure for express app, but with mongoose the model library has different use.
Where i put my schemes?
https://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html

```
project/
  controllers/
    comments.js
    index.js
    users.js
  helpers/
    dates.js
  middlewares/
    auth.js
    users.js
  models/
    comment.js
    user.js
  public/
    libs/
    css/
    img/
  views/
    comments/
      comment.jade
    users/
    index.jade
  tests/
    controllers/
    models/
      comment.js
    middlewares/
    integration/
    ui/
  .gitignore
  app.js
  package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You put your Schemas in the models folder.Using mongoose you can then create the model for each Schema in its file, and then export the model. You can also exports some functions operating on your models in the same file, such as Model.findAll(), Model.findById(id) ...